# Check box always to the left of its label, how can I move it to the right?

Tags: html, css

Here is my html and css. How can I make the label on the right for a right to left language? This is taken from the free html5 template massively.

The check box always to the left of its label, how can I move it to the right?

```css
 input[type="checkbox"],
 input[type="radio"] {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  z-index: -1;
 }

  input[type="checkbox"] + label,
  input[type="radio"] + label {
   text-decoration: none;
   cursor: pointer;
   display: inline-block;
   font-size: 1rem;
   letter-spacing: 0;
   font-family: "Merriweather", Georgia, serif;
   text-transform: none;
   font-weight: 300;
   padding-left: 2.8rem;
   padding-right: 1rem;
   position: relative;
  }

   input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
   input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    text-rendering: auto;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none !important;
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    font-weight: 900;
   }

   input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
   input[type="radio"] + label:before {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: solid 2px;
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8rem;
    height: 1.8rem;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 1.65rem;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: -0.125rem;
    width: 1.8rem;
   }
```

```html
  <div class="col-12">
   <input type="checkbox" id="demo-copy" name="demo-copy">
   <label for="demo-copy">show password</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Try `left:100%;` on the `label:before`

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
input[type="checkbox"],
input[type="radio"] {
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -ms-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  margin-right: -2rem;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  z-index: -1;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label,
input[type="radio"]+label {
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 1rem;
  letter-spacing: 0;
  font-family: "Merriweather", Georgia, serif;
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 2.8rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  /* this */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label:before,
input[type="radio"]+label:before {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  display: inline-block;
  font-style: normal;
  font-variant: normal;
  text-rendering: auto;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none !important;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-weight: 900;
}

input[type="checkbox"]+label:before,
input[type="radio"]+label:before {
  border-radius: 0;
  border: solid 2px;
  content: '';
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  height: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.65rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 1.8rem;
  margin: 0 1em;
}

.col-12 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}


}
```

```html
<div class="col-12">
  <input type="checkbox" id="demo-copy" name="demo-copy">
  <label for="demo-copy">show password</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the label to be first.

```html
<label for="check">My Checkbox</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="check">
```

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to apply CSS to type="checkbox" and label.

All you need to do is just move `<label>` tag before the `<input>` tag as below.

```html
<label for="demo-copy">show password</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="demo-copy" name="demo-copy">
```